# grunt-contrib-requirejs task stops Grunt without errors

Tags: node.js, requirejs, gruntjs, r.js, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have a problem where my `grunt-contrib-requirejs` task stops my grunt processes. It does this with no errors at all. I need help identifying the issue.

**My overall task**

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'jshint',
    'handlebars',
    'requirejs',
    'concat:dist',
    'uglify',
    'compass',
    'imagemin',
    'cssmin',
    'copy'
]);
```

**This is my task configuration**

```
requirejs: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: 'app',
            optimize: 'none',
            optimizeCss: 'none', // We use cssmin for this
            preserveLicenseComments: true,
            dir: 'dist/',

            useStrict: true,
            wrap: false,
            findNestedDependencies: true,

            //If set to true, any files that were combined into a build bundle will be
            //removed from the output folder.
            removeCombined: true,

            paths: {
                aura: '<%= settings.bower %>/aura/lib/aura',
                underscore: '<%= settings.bower %>/underscore/underscore',
                eventemitter: '<%= settings.bower %>/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2',
                backbone: '<%= settings.bower %>/backbone/backbone',
                handlebars: '<%= settings.bower %>/handlebars/handlebars',
                text: '<%= settings.bower %>/requirejs-text/text',
                jquery: '<%= settings.bower %>/jquery/jquery'
            },

            shim: {
                backbone: {
                    exports: 'Backbone',
                    deps: ['underscore', 'jquery']
                },
                underscore: {
                    exports: '_'
                },
                handlebars: {
                    exports: 'Handlebars'
                }
            },

            modules: [{
                name: "app",
                include: ["aura","jquery"]
            }],

            onBuildWrite: function( name, path, contents ) {
                grunt.log.writeln( 'Writing: ' + name );
                return contents
            },

            done: function(done, output) {
                var duplicates = require('rjs-build-analysis').duplicates(output);

                if (duplicates.length > 0) {
                    grunt.log.subhead('Duplicates found in requirejs build:');
                    grunt.log.warn(duplicates);
                    done(new Error('r.js built duplicate modules, please check the excludes option.'));
                }

                grunt.log.writeln('All done');

                done();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I tried running it with the `-v` flag, but I get no errors or warnings. It then just stops, and does not run the other tasks that I defined, I don't get the custom loggings that I defined. I get this output:

```
Running "requirejs" task

Running "requirejs:dist" (requirejs) task
Verifying property requirejs.dist exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: logLevel=0, done=undefined, baseUrl="app", optimize="none", optimizeCss="none", preserveLicenseComments, dir="dist/", useStrict, wrap=false, findNestedDependencies, removeCombined, paths={"aura":"bower_components/aura/lib/aura","underscore":
"bower_components/underscore/underscore","eventemitter":"bower_components/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2","backbone":"bower_components/backbone/backbone","handlebars":"bower_components/handlebars/handlebars","text":"bower_components/requirejs-text/t
ext","jquery":"bower_components/jquery/jquery"}, shim={"backbone":{"exports":"Backbone","deps":["underscore","jquery"]},"underscore":{"exports":"_"},"handlebars":{"exports":"Handlebars"}}, modules=[{"name":"app","include":["aura","jquery"]}], onBuild
Write=undefined
>> Tracing dependencies for: app
```

It seems from this output that the done function is not defined, but I did define it, I even used a example from the [grunt-contrib-requirejs readme](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs#done).

I'm using `grunt@0.4.1` and `grunt-contrib-requirejs@0.4.1` with `requirejs@2.1.8`. Node is version `v0.8.16`

### Update one

I tried upgrading my Node, I'm now on `v0.10.17` but no changes here.

I removed `aura` from my modules include, it now looks like this:

```
modules: [{
    name: "app",
    include: ["jquery"]
}],
```

This gave me a little more input, but it still stops my Grunt, and does not run my done function, I get this output:

```
>> app.js
>> ----------------
>> bower_components/aura/lib/platform.js
>> bower_components/aura/lib/base.js
>> bower_components/aura/lib/logger.js
>> bower_components/aura/lib/aura.extensions.js
>> bower_components/aura/lib/aura.js
>> app.js
```

Comment: I would try 2 things to try to find where the problem is: 1. It seems to me according to [this example](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) that you set your base url wrong. it should be **'app/'**  2. Try to skim down your options for requirejs to a bare essential minimum, and see if it's still not running. I would guess that currently it's  stuck on locating dependencies for your app **app**. Try those things and we'll see what else can be done

Comment: I tried both things, but no luck - still the same output.

Comment: I removed the `aura` from my include and it seems to work now, at least finding dependencies, but after that it stops my grunt and does not run my done function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `done` function is failing and the grunt task wasn't set up to forward the error to you. I made a [PR that you can look at here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs/pull/67) to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem as a issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs/issues/37

But there is no solution yet, I might have to look in to the error myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the entire "done" section from the requireJS options, it won't halt the task list execution, however you will loose the ability to perform analysis on your compiled code

Comment: This is what I did, but by solution I want it to work not just remove it. It's still not working and I have not had the time to look at it.